# Django rest bad request error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class Scenario(models.Model):
    tasks = models.ManyToManyField(Task, blank=True)
```

Its serializer:

```
class ScenarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Scenario
        fields = '__all__'
```

and a view to create a scenario:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def scenarios_list(request):
    """
    List all scenarios, or create a new.
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        scenarios = Scenario.objects.all()
        serializer = ScenarioSerializer(scenarios, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = ScenarioSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(
                serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am sending following data from my frontend:

```
[
    {id: 3, title: "Three", how_often: "DS", how_important_task: "EI", role: "Lorem", …},

    {id: 1, title: "One", how_often: "MO", how_important_task: "RI", role: "Lorem", …},

    {id: 6, title: "Six", how_often: "WO", how_important_task: "EI", role: "", …},

    {id: 4, title: "Four", how_often: "", how_important_task: "", role: "", …}
]
```

Which throws me BAD REQUEST error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you look what inside the `serializer.errors`?

Comment: You explicitly return bad request if the serializer is not valid. The response contains the errors, so you should look at them. Almost certainly, the issue is that you are sending data for Tasks, but the serializer is for Scenarios.